# Difference between {parameter} and parameter?

Tags: node.js

I have the following code from a lib and I am wondering what is the difference between having a parameter/variable enclosed with {} and one without them?

the line I am refering to is this one:

```
send({sessionId}, {text})
```

Here's the full code:

```
const actions = {
  send({sessionId}, {text}) {
    // Our bot has something to say!
    // Let's retrieve the Facebook user whose session belongs to
    const recipientId = sessions[sessionId].fbid;
    if (recipientId) {
      // Yay, we found our recipient!
      // Let's forward our bot response to her.
      // We return a promise to let our bot know when we're done sending
      return fbMessage(recipientId, text)
      .then(() => null)
      .catch((err) => {
        console.error(
          'Oops! An error occurred while forwarding the response to',
          recipientId,
          ':',
          err.stack || err
        );
      });
    } else {
      console.error('Oops! Couldn\'t find user for session:', sessionId);
      // Giving the wheel back to our bot
      return Promise.resolve()
    }
  },
  // You should implement your custom actions here
  // See https://wit.ai/docs/quickstart
};
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a destructuring operator, it means that `send()` accepts two arguments: an object with a `sessionId` key, and an object with a `text` key.

A valid call will look somewhat like this:

```
actions.send({sessionId: 42}, {text: "Hello World!"});
```

It also works the other way! so you can call it like this:

```
let sessionId = 42;
let text = "Hello World!";

// Here it means {sessionId: sessionId}, {text: text}
action.send({sessionId}, {text});
```

Comment: Thank you, Madara Uchiha! Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

`{ sessionId }` is code that uses the EcmaScript 6 syntax for creating objects. It is equivalent to writing `{ sessionId: sessionId }` using the older syntax. So `send({sessionId}, {text})` means that the `send` function is called with two objects whilst `send(sessionId, text)` means that the `send` function is called with (probably) two strings.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts Because the answer is wrong. The function isn't called in the example, it's defined.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha maybe the explanation is incorrect but the gist is not. Yours is downvoted too, are you saying you're wrong?